# Binary division non restoring method

Tags: binary

I have no idea how this works, at -7 it is shifted to get -14 then the 1 is brought down to give -13
Why exactrly do you keep adding the divisor?

Source: [https://userpages.umbc.edu/~squire/cs411_l10.html](https://userpages.umbc.edu/%7Esquire/cs411_l10.html)

[image]

Comment: No this is non restoring method

Comment: There's no point digging through some web page to try and explain what the author writes. If you want to understand the non-restoring method, then just ask. It's easy to explain and defend here. But I've no interest arguing with your understanding of someone else's writing. I have no problem, on the other hand, in helping you understand my writing of it. Then you can go back and try to apply your own acquired understanding to that page, if you like, on your own time.

Comment: This is off topic - it belongs either on mathematics or on stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay please explain to my the non restoring method of binary division

Comment: I don't know if this is on-topic at those sites, so I'll close it.